# Dynamic variables in PHP from enum

Tags: php

Related to the question [Verb conjugator for French](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111847/78136), I was asked an question on whether one could *summarize all the `$exceptionIs<NAME_OF_EXCEPTION> = $exceptionmodel-> getValue() === ExceptionModel::NAME_OF_EXCEPTION` lines*. In other words, can one make dynamic variables out of the comparison of a value combined with all values of an enum?

As I'm a bit rusty in php, I made this version, and ask you whether this is a good solution, or if it needs major refactoring. To avoid posting other peoples code, I've mocked the `ExceptionModel` class, and replace the output of `ExceptionModel::getConstants()` with a predefined array. This to give you working code to review.  The original code is located on github, as the classes [ExceptionModel](https://github.com/GrischaK/french_conjugation/blob/ef9d986ef7682eb62f88fcbd4c9f5025535eb0cb/classes/ExceptionModel.php) and [Enum](https://github.com/GrischaK/french_conjugation/blob/ef9d986ef7682eb62f88fcbd4c9f5025535eb0cb/classes/Enum.php).

```
<?php
// A mockup of the original ExceptionModel inheriting from Enum
class ExceptionModel {
    const NO_EXCEPTIONS = 'no_exception';
    const ALLER = 'aller';
    const AVOIR_IRR = 'avoir_irr';
    const ETRE_IRR = 'etre_irr';

    // ... many more lines ...

    function getConstants() {
        // ... returns array of constants ...
    }
}


function myFunction($exception) {
    // In final version, it should use the following line
    // $exceptionModels = ExceptionModel::getConstants();

    // ... but for now, use this array
    $exceptionModels = array (
        "NO_EXCEPTIONS" => 'no_exception',
        "ALLER" => 'aller',
        "AVOIR_IRR" => 'avoir_irr',
        "ETRE_IRR" => 'etre_irr'
    );

    // Generate dynamic variables testing for equality of
    // of $exception and an Enum value from ExceptionModel
    foreach ($exceptionModels as $constName => $constValue) {
        ${'exceptionIs' . $constName} = $exception === $constValue;
    }

    if ($exceptionIsALLER) {
        echo "ExceptionModel is aller. ";
    }

    else if ($exceptionIsAVOIR_IRR) {
        echo "ExceptionModel is avoir_irr";
    } else {
        echo "ExceptionModel was neither, it is: " . $exception;
    }

    echo "\n";
}

echo "<pre>";
myFunction("none");
myFunction(ExceptionModel::ALLER);
myFunction(ExceptionModel::AVOIR_IRR);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

This correctly produces the output:

```
ExceptionModel was neither, it is: none
ExceptionModel is aller. 
ExceptionModel is avoir_irr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach to creating the temporary variables, is to use reflection and automatically define test function for equality to any given enum value.

If extending the base `Enum` class, or the `ExtensionModel` class with the following function:

```
function __call($func, $param) {
    $func_prefix = substr($func, 0, 2);
    $func_const = substr($func, 2);
    if ($func_prefix == "is") {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass(get_class($this));
        return $this->getValue() === $reflection->getConstant($func_const);
    }
}
```

Then it is legal to do stuff like in the following test function:

```
function myFunction(ExceptionModel $exceptionModel, Tense $tense) {

    if ($exceptionModel->isALLER()
        && $tense->isPresent() ) {
        ... do something ...
    }
```

given that both `ExceptionModel` and `Tense` inherits from the `Enum` class. In other words, now you can do `$enumobject->is<ENUM_VALUE>()` for any enum value inheriting from `Enum`.

Answer (score 2):

PHP allows [computed variable names](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), but it's nearly always a bad idea.  Unless you are careful about variable naming conventions, you could easily trash a variable accidentally, possibly introducing a security vulnerability.

You would be better off using an associative array.

```
// Generate dynamic variables testing for equality of
// of $exception and an Enum value from ExceptionModel
foreach ($exceptionModels as $constName => $constValue) {
    $detected[$constName] = $exception === $constValue;
}

if ($detected['ALLER']) {
    echo "ExceptionModel is aller.";
} else if ($detected['AVOIR_IRR']) {
    echo "ExceptionModel is avoir_irr.";
} else {
    echo "ExceptionModel was neither, it is: " . $exception;
}
```

Comment: In general I do agree with you, but in this particular case I see a point in doing this, or even doing automatically as suggested in my own answer. The risk of trashing a variable should be small as we're talking about constants within `Enum` classes.